# Remove url parameters in react-oidc

Tags: reactjs, oauth, openid-connect, react-oidc

I'm using [AxaGuilDEv/react-oidc](https://github.com/AxaGuilDEv/react-oidc) which is based on [react-oidc](https://github.com/bjerkio/oidc-react) package to login using oauth. The url called during signin has the following params by default : `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, `response_type`, `scope`, `state`, `code_challenge`, `code_challenge_method`, `response_mode`.

I found out how to add more params to the url, but I can't figure out how to remove the `code_challenge` & `code_challenge_method` params.

Is there a way to do that in either of the packages?

Answer (score 0):

**code_challenge** and the **code_challenge_method** is part of the PKCE security feature and it is a good practice to keep using. Look in the documentation if you can disable PKCE in the OIDC server. If PKCE is required or not is controlled in the OIDC-server.

Comment: Yes I understand, but for now I just need a way to remove those parameters from the url, or any other param I need to remove.

Comment: Why do you need to remove them?

Comment: I need to test why a get `invalid_grant` error when I keep them, and also I need to know how to easily edit the url as I want, adding or removing any of the parameters to understand the workflow better.

Comment: What does the OIDC server log say? I suspect  you got some issues with the scopes.

Comment: I don't have access to the server. But when I used another simpler react `package` (with less functionalities than I prefer), the signin url didn't have `challenge_code` & `code_challenge_method` params, then the login was successful and I could retrieve the token/userdata, but when I use the `oidc-react package`, which adds those two params automatically, I get `invalid_grant` error.

Comment: You could always use a tool like postman or Fiddler to do a manual authentication against your server. In Fiddler you can for example use breakpoints, to modify requests in realtime.